# How do I write services that communicate with an R model for an android application?

Tags: android, mysql, r

I am building a recommendation model in R which needs to be used in an Android application. What I am confused about is how do I establish a communication between them? I have never tried using R with a web or an android app. If there are any services to be written between the app and R, how is that done?

**Current Scenario:**
The team here is using a MySQL database with their Android app and PHP for their sever side code. The recommendation model simply needs to be invoked by a click of a button in the app to generate recommendations.

So how does this flow i.e from the app to the model occur is what I need help with.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a web service. To do so, there are a few choices:

- opencpu https://www.opencpu.org/
- deployR https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/
- rApache
- and others